# Что означает запись вида 192.168.0.0/16 ?

Tags: сеть

Помогите осознать значение /16.

Или вот пример из книги:

```
fe80::f00 = fe80:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0f00
fe80::f00/64 = fe80:0000:0000:0000:****:****:****:****
             = fe80::/64
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это записи так называемых бесклассовых сетей. 192.168.0.0 - это понятная для людей запись четырехбайтовых адресов протокола Internet версии 4. /16 - означает первые 16 бит = 2 байта в этой записи - маска подсети. Другие два байта описывают адрес конкретного узла в этой подсети (от 0.1 до 254.254).
192.168.0.0/24 уже значило бы подсеть 192.168.0 с адресами внутри нее от единицы до 254.

```
fe80::f00 = fe80:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0f00
fe80::f00/64 = fe80:0000:0000:0000:****:****:****:****
             = fe80::/64
```

Приведенный выше пример показывает краткую нотацию адресов протокола Internet версии 6. Как видно их принято записывать в виде шестнадцатеричных октетов разделенных двоеточиями. Два идущих подряд двоеточия означают большую последовательность нулевых октетов (байтов). /64 означает то же самое что и в версии 4 - маску подсети.

Comment: Первые байты слева направо 1.2.3.4 (это номера байтов) или 4.3.2.1?
т.е. /24 равносильно маске 255.255.255.0 ?

Comment: Именно. Равносильно.

Comment: Хм, октет по моему мнению - это восемь элементов чего-то там. Но в IPv6 двоеточиями разделяются каждые два байта (что явно не 8, а 16). Видимо имелось ввиду, что IPv6 адрес - это октет, который состоит из 8ми, разделенных двоеточиями 4х-значных 16-ричных чисел (в отличие от IPv4, где действительно, точками разделялись именно октеты).

Comment: Да, с IPv6 лопухнулся. Там не октеты.

Answer (score 11):

Основывается эта радость на VLSM.
Различают сеть (network, **адрес сети**), хост (host, **адрес хоста**) и маску сети (**network mask**), это разные три понятия.

Маска по большому счету определяет границу между адресом сети и адресом хоста в этой сети.

/16 это лишь длина маски, т.е. количество единичных бит слева (в скобках система счисления):

```
/0 = 00000000.00000000.00000000.00000000(2) = 0.0.0.0(10)
/1 = 10000000.00000000.00000000.00000000(2) = 128.0.0.0(10)
...
/8 = 11111111.00000000.00000000.00000000(2) = 255.0.0.0(10)
...
/16 = 11111111.11111111.00000000.00000000(2) = 255.255.0.0(10)
...
/24 = 11111111.11111111.11111111.00000000(2) = 255.255.255.0(10)
...
/32 = 11111111.11111111.11111111.11111111(2) = 255.255.255.255(10)
```

В процессе наложения (битовое "и") маски на адрес (будь то сеть или хост) вы получаете адрес сети (именно сети). Т.е. в вашем случае, вы берете адрес 192.168.55.25 и маску 16-битной длины через битовое "и", получаете = 192.168.0.0 (ваша сеть).
В десятичной системе:

```
192.168.55.25 & 255.255.0.0 = 192.168.0.0
```

В двоичной системе:

```
11000000.10101000.00110111.00011001 & 11111111.11111111.00000000.00000000 = 
11000000.10101000.00000000.00000000
```

Вот как это работает. И используется это не в nmap для упрощения, а, например, в CIDR, не говоря уже о различных подсчетах и алгоритмах распределения адресного пространства.

**Что касается**

```
fe80::f00 = fe80:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0f00
fe80::f00/64 = fe80:0000:0000:0000:****:****:****:****
             = fe80::/64
```

Это действительно адрес в нотации IPv6.
fe80 - это Link Local т.е. IP-адрес который может взаимодействовать только внутри локальной сети. /64 это также нотация CIDR аналогичная нотации в IPv4, которую я описал выше, только она несколько больше, так как IPv6 адрес = 128битам.

Для Link-local:

Минимальная длина маски - 10 (т.е. 10 неизменных бит с начала (слева))

```
fe80::/10 это диапазон fe80:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000 - 
febf:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff
```

Для вашего случая:

Т.е. для /64 первые 64 бита будут неизменными:

```
fe80::/64 это диапазон fe80:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000 -     
fe80:0000:0000:0000:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff
```

Вот как-то так.

Comment: Dex абсолютно прав
